# Vim change list behaviour

Tags: vim, changelist

I'm trying to grok the change list on vim and I'm having trouble understanding the following behavior:

As example I insert the following text:

```
I like chips and fish.
```

Realized I got the nouns in the wrong order, so I want to get:

```
I like fish and chips.
```

Starting with a fresh vim instance with no .vimrc (`vim -u NONE`) this is exactly what I do (# are just for explanation):

```
iI like chips and fish.<Esc>  # Insert text. Realize I want to switch the words
Fc                            # Jump back to 'chips'
de                            # Delete the word (and put it in anon register)
ff                            # Jump to the 'fish' word
vep                           # Select the word, and paste from anon register
g;                            # Try to jump back to the position where I change
                              # the word 'chips'. It doesn't work and I get:
E19: Mark has invalid line number

# To see what is going on i print the change list:
:changes
    change line  col text
        2     1   12 I like  and chips.
        1     2   12 -invalid-
    >
```

My first question is why the jump didn't work in the first place?

Second, the `-invalid-` entry of the change list doesn't make any sense to me. As you saw I never went beyond line 1. Why is an entry with line 2?

Im using Vim 7.4.52

**Update:** The -invalid- seems to be a bug. I already reported it:

https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=283

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. That is clearly a bug. I have posted a [patch](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/48111) to the vim_dev mailinglist.

Comment: Sorry, i read your comment late. Just to let you know I've reported it. See update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default Vim on Mac OS X (7.3 Normal version without GUI, no patches), `g;` moves the cursor to the `c` in `chips` and the output of `:changes` is different from yours:

```
change line  col text
>   0     1   16 I like fish and chops.
```

The fact that only *one* change is remembered is consistent with this paragraph from `:help g;`

```
When two undo-able changes are in the same line and at a column position less
than 'textwidth' apart only the last one is remembered.  This avoids that a
sequence of small changes in a line, for example "xxxxx", adds many positions
to the change list.  When 'textwidth' is zero 'wrapmargin' is used.  When that
also isn't set a fixed number of 79 is used.  Detail: For the computations
bytes are used, not characters, to avoid a speed penalty (this only matters
for multi-byte encodings).
```

so everything is normal (if a bit surprising).

With a reasonably recent MacVim (7.4.258), I get the behavior you describe for `g;` and a *slightly* different `:changes` output ("fish" is missing in yours):

```
change line  col text
    1     1   16 I like fish and chips.
>   0     2   16 -invalid-
```

It smells *a lot* like you discovered a bug and I strongly suggest you notify [the vim_dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_dev) about it (if they are not already aware).

Comment: In summary: 1) doing `g;` will never work to acomplish what I want (because it will only remember the last change on the line). 2) the -invalid- is problably a bug. Right?

Comment: Yes, within the limits described in the doc, and yes. Note that you can use `m<backtick>` before a jump to arbitrarily remember where you come from.

Comment: I was trying to improve the exercise on page 151 from the book Practical Vim, which does it as you say with marks before the jump. Just seems a redundant to put a mark where there is already another mark (from the change list). Sadly the docs have also a good point about keeping only the last change on the line.